# Swapping two pointers to pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function which takes a pointer to an array (so an `int**`). In this function, I'd like to call `swap(int*, int*)` to swap the location of two of the elements in the array. What is the syntax in C for swapping these two elements?

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
int* do_something(int** arr) {
    // assume i and j are valid locations in the array
    swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]); // what should this line be?
}

// this function works fine, no changes needed
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: just remove `&` symbols

Comment: You need to dereference the pointer in `do_something`.

Comment: For future reference, the term "double pointer" might be misconstrued as: `double* a;`.  Though, on the other hand, saying "pointer to a pointer to an integer" is a bit wordy.

Comment: I actually ran into that exact problem when I was googling this earlier. Thanks for pointing that out, it could be confusing.

Comment: You are not passing pointer to array, you are passing pointer to pointer. Note that it's very rare to pass pointer to array in C, you usually pass pointer to first item in the array.

Comment: A pointer to an array would be for example: `int (*arr)[5]` and the dimension is required by standard

Comment: @KeithThompson I used to say the same thing, so I wouldn't worry about it too much. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me what `arr` is. Is it an array of `int*`, or is it a pointer to an array of `int`?

**Option 1**: `arr` is an array of `int*`:

Your swap function swaps `int` variables, but you need to swap `int*` variables. You therefore need an extra level of indirection in the swap function.

```
void swap(int** a, int** b) 
{
    int* temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

**Option 2**: `arr` is a pointer to an array of `int`:

In this case, you wish to swap two `int` values, and the variant of `swap` that appears in the question does just that. The problem is that you have defined `do_something` incorrectly. It should receive an `int*` and be implemented like this:

```
void do_something(int* arr, int i, int j) 
{
    swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
}
```

Comment: Option 2 is what I am attempting to accomplish. By redefining do_something the way you showed, it can make changes to the original array right? So back in the function that calls do_something, the swap should show up?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `&` symbols. Array elements are already accessed using pointers.

When you say

```
arr[i]
```

you are actually saying

```
*(arr + i)
```

So you are already passing a pointer to `do_something`.

Since `arr` contains pointers to integers (`int*`), then saying `arr[i]` you are accessing the `int*` at i-th position so you can just pass it into your swap method that accepts `int *`

Comment: `arr` is a pointer to pointer to int. wont doing `arr+1` make `arr` increment by `8 bytes` (if address size is 8)? 
i think what he needs is `(*arr) + i)`

Comment: derefencing a pointer to pointer to int once makes it point to the value??

Comment: Actually, in this case since it is an array of `int *`, I think both of us are correct. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
```

should be something like

```
swap( ((*arr) + i), ((*arr) + j) );
```

Since `arr` points to the base address of the array, dereferencing it makes it same as the base address of the array, then incrementing by `i` or `j` would make it point to the corresponding element.